# Any hints on how to clean up in the own created roles?

Tags: user-management, role-management

We have an old Sitecore installation, and I need to clean up and consolidate our own created roles. We have partial overlapping roles and too many to make them useful.

So to be more precise-how do I extract the rights from two roles and merge the two into one new role and delete the old one’s?

Answer (score 1):

You could write an SQL script to identify and remove roles. The below Script gives you all Roles that are not used by any user currently.

A few points before run:

1. You need read rights on your DB.
2. Execute this script on your Core DB
3. Before deleting roles that appear here check if they are assigned to other roles!!!
4. Please also do not delete Sitecore roles!!!

```
/*START*/
BEGIN


    PRINT '***********************************';
    PRINT 'Roles without users';
    PRINT '***********************************';
    declare @ApplicationID nvarchar(128);
    declare @RoleID nvarchar(128);
    declare @RoleName nvarchar(128);
    declare @LoweredRoleName nvarchar(128);
    declare @Description nvarchar(128);

    declare @URUserId nvarchar(128);
    declare @URRoleId nvarchar(128);
    declare @URuserName nvarchar(128);
    declare @URLoweredUserName nvarchar(128);

    declare @rowcount int=0;
    declare @totalcount int=0;

    
    /*Cursor to retrieve all roles*/
    DECLARE ALL_ROLES CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT [ApplicationId]
                  ,[RoleId]
                  ,[RoleName]
                  ,[LoweredRoleName]
                  ,[Description]
              FROM aspnet_roles
              ORDER BY [RoleName];

    
        OPEN ALL_ROLES; 
        FETCH NEXT FROM ALL_ROLES into @ApplicationID, @RoleID, @RoleName, @LoweredRoleName , @Description;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
             BEGIN 

                SET @rowcount = 0;

                
                /*Check if Role has Users*/
                DECLARE ALL_USERS_IN_ROLES CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT ur.UserId
                      ,ur.RoleId
                      ,u.userName
                      ,u.LoweredUserName
                  FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles ur, aspnet_Users u
                  WHERE ur.UserId  = u.UserId
                  AND ur.RoleId = @RoleID;

                  OPEN ALL_USERS_IN_ROLES; 
                    FETCH NEXT FROM ALL_USERS_IN_ROLES into @URUserId, @URRoleId, @URuserName, @URLoweredUserName;
                    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
                         BEGIN 
                            SET @rowcount = @rowcount + 1;
                            /*PRINT '    User' + ': ' + @URuserName;*/
                            FETCH NEXT FROM ALL_USERS_IN_ROLES into @URUserId, @URRoleId, @URuserName, @URLoweredUserName;

                         END;

                    CLOSE ALL_USERS_IN_ROLES; 
                    DEALLOCATE ALL_USERS_IN_ROLES;

                    if @rowcount = 0
                        BEGIN
                            PRINT 'Role' + ': ' + @RoleName;
                            SET @totalcount = @totalcount + 1;
                        END;
                
                FETCH NEXT FROM ALL_ROLES into @ApplicationID, @RoleID, @RoleName, @LoweredRoleName , @Description;

             END;

        CLOSE ALL_ROLES; 
        DEALLOCATE ALL_ROLES; 

        PRINT 'Count: ' + CAST(@totalcount AS VARCHAR);

END;
/*END*/
```

Credit: [Cleanup your Roles](https://www.from-sitecore-with-love.de/blog/2017/roles-without-users)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it by clearing security roles in Sitecore using C#. Here is a code snippet you can enhance further. This will clear the access rights from items.

```
role role = role.fromname("everyone");
accessrulecollection accessrules = item.security.getaccessrules();

foreach (var accessright in _accessrights)
{
   accessright right = accessright.fromname(accessright.value);
   accessrules.helper.removeexactmatches(role, right, propagationtype.any);
}
item.security.setaccessrules(accessrules);
```

Once you remove the access rights, you can delete that role.

Refer to these threads for more details.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759017/how-to-clear-security-role-in-sitecore

https://www.appsloveworld.com/csharp/100/281/how-to-clear-security-role-in-sitecore

Hope this helps.